# No identifier specified for entity in java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate and i mapped my table with my bean. If i am not assign any particular column value as @id, it throws "No identifier specified for entity" error, however it is not primary key in my data table. I want to add multiple records with same data. how can i do it? When i annotated my product Name column with @id my code runs perfect.

Comment: Why don't you create `id` property?

Comment: I suggest you create an additional field called `id` which can be auto-generated and make that field as your primary id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate requires an identifier for each entity. However, it is possible to use [native queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) to [insert](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/HibernateInsert.shtml) new records. And, in the same way, to [recover](http://www.mastertheboss.com/query/using-native-queries-with-hibernate-and-jpa) them.